# XCode 4.5 Stopped building my framework

Tags: xcode, frameworks, ios6

Updating to XCode 4.5 seems to have broken something in my build settings and I can no longer spit out a .framework binary. It generates the Headers and all the rest of the files except for the actual binary.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: The problem seems to be armv6 architecture. Apple apparently stopped supporting armv6 in XCode 4.5 and later. So now what? We're supposed to drop support for this architecture also? I'm not sure how that works... considering that if you resubmit and app and drop support of a certain architecture, the app will get rejected...

/confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep drop it. Armv6 is the iPhone 3G and I think the iPod touch v3? In any case pretty old devices that apple doesn't want us building apps for any more. They don't even run iOS 5 as far as I know.